# Check if credentials are cached for tf.exe

Tags: powershell, tf-cli

How would I check if my credentials are already cached for a specific server using tf.exe? I am trying to do slight automation for tfs get and workspace/workfold configuration. The assumption is that most machines already have the credentials cached, but I want to be able to double check beforehand, and throw an error in powershell if they are not.

Thank you,

Derongan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using vaultcmd.exe e.g.:

```
vaultcmd /listcreds:"Windows Credentials" /all
```

You could run that through a Where-Object command looking for a string that matches the TFS server name.